# HP EliteBook 840 G6 disconnect from WiFi: Hotkey/gesture?

Tags: wireless-networking, hp-elitebook

My EliteBook 840 G6 is constantly disconnecting from WiFi networks.  This is observed at different locations and WiFi networks.  It doesn't turn off WiFi, as I can still see the list of networks and reconnect.  So it isn't going into Airplane Mode.

I find that the EliteBook 840 G6 has a very "touchy" keyboard and touchpad.  There are phantom clicks, and sometimes, the keyboard goes into a weird mode where key strokes don't have the desired effect.  When in this mode, none of the little lights on some of the buttons are lit to indicate that the keyboard is *supposed* to be in a different mode, e.g., "fn", "numlk".

I wonder if the flakiness of the keyboard/touchpad is making it seem like I pressed a hotkey to disconnect from the WiFi network.  Is there a shortcut to disconnet from a WiFi network without going into Airplane Mode?

I appreciate that there are suggested actions to take due to the apparent prevalence of EliteBooks disconnecting from WiFi networks, but my question is not about that.  It is specifically about whether there are hotkeys, shortcuts, touchpad gestures, or some combination thereof that can cause a disconnection from the WiFi network.  It could be specific to Windows 10 and/or the Elitebook line and/or 840 G6.

Thanks.